# Linux: Pipe output in File until

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, logfile

Does anyone know how I can pipe output to file until filesize reaches limit or is canceled by other condition? Is this possible?

How can I cancel writing output to file ('$cmd >> file.txt 2>&1') with conditions like filesize, time duration ...?

EDIT: I start an application and I need the first ~1000 lines of output, without stopping the application itself! Logging complete application lifetime is not wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

`seq 10000 | tee -i somefile | head -n 1000`

This will capture all the data from seq into somefile and 1000 lines will print to stdout. You have to use tee -i to ignore interrupts, otherwise when head ends it will interrupt tee which will interrupt seq.

Comment: However `seq` in your example will finish working whereas OP would like to see `without stopping the application itself!`

Comment: @skwllsp I changed it to used 'tee -i'. It should allow seq to continue.

Answer (score 1):

For time constraint, use `timeout`. For size constraint, use `tee --max-bytes`.

If what you seek is log files management, you should consider using `rsyslogd`, which handle for you log rotation, size, time, etc.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee does not mention `--max-bytes`. On my RHEL it is also not available: `tee: unrecognized option '--max-bytes'`

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout kills also the command, so perhaps calling a application in cmd will kill app also.

Answer (score 1):

> I need the first ~1000 lines of output, without stopping the application itself!

1) 
I think a simple way to do this is to pipe to `sed` with two rules. The first rule '1,1000w head-lines.txt' is used to save to the file head-lines.txt, the second rule is used to print.

Write to a file first 1000 lines, print all lines:

```
$ seq 1000000000000 | sed -n -e '1,1000w head-lines.txt' -e '1,$p'
```

Write to a file first 1000 lines, print all lines, starting from 1001:

```
$ seq 1000000000000 | sed -n -e '1,1000w head-lines.txt' -e '1001,$p'
```

References:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-how-to-execute-multiple-sed-commands/

2)
A bit more complicated way is to handle SIGPIPE in bash. In bash I will run `seq 100000000` which runs long on my server and get only first 1000 lines of its output in file:

```
$ trap "" SIGPIPE && seq 100000000 2>/dev/null  | head -n 1000 > your.log
```

When `head` will get first 1000 line it will end and normally SIGPIPE will be sent to `seq`. However I call `trap` in order to ignore SIGPIPE:

```
$ help trap
trap: trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
    Trap signals and other events.

    If ARG is the null string each SIGNAL_SPEC is ignored by the
    shell and by the commands it invokes.
```